# su - user is not doing anything

Tags: ubuntu, su

I am entering to an Ubuntu Server using root, and I need to run a background process as a more limited user, so I write

```
su -l limitedUser -c 'programName'
```

But nothing happens. Even if programName is something like echo, nothing is being executed. What could be going on? Is there a log I could take a look at?

PS: I know nothing is being executed as TOP or PS AFX don't show anything new running.

Comment: What happens if you `su` to limitedUser with `su -l limitedUser` and then, when you get the prompt, type `programName<ENTER>`? Does it run at all? Remember that, as answered by Ярослав below, the user has to be enabled and have a shell like `/bin/bash`, etc (not something like `/bin/false`).

Comment: The problem was that it was pointing to /bin/false like you said. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The user has to be enabled (have password set, not be expired, etc).

It is possible that your su does not issue a warning like mine. You may consult */var/log/auth.log* to see what is happening

```
# su apache -c bash
This account is currently not available.
# tail -n 10 /var/log/auth.log 
Oct 17 05:53:16 geee su[30744]: Successful su for apache by root
Oct 17 05:53:16 geee su[30744]: + /dev/pts/11 root:apache
Oct 17 05:53:17 geee su[30744]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user apache by (uid=0)
Oct 17 05:53:17 geee nologin: Attempted login by jaroslav on /dev/pts/11
Oct 17 05:53:17 geee su[30744]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user apache
Oct 17 05:53:20 geee su[30748]: Successful su for apache by root
Oct 17 05:53:20 geee su[30748]: + /dev/pts/11 root:apache
Oct 17 05:53:20 geee su[30748]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user apache by (uid=0)
Oct 17 05:53:20 geee nologin: Attempted login by jaroslav on /dev/pts/11
Oct 17 05:53:20 geee su[30748]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user apache
```